# Confusion about the proper time interval along an arbitrary worldline

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, spacetime, equivalence-principle

Let us consider the worldline $x^\mu(\lambda)$ of an observer moving in an arbitrary manner (i.e. possibly non-inertial). If we want to write down the proper time interval measured by that observer between two points $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ on its trajectory, we use the formula $$\Delta\tau=\int\limits_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}d\lambda\sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}}$$ instead of $$\Delta\tau=\int\limits_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}d\lambda\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}(x)\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}}.$$

Aren't acceleration effects mimicked by the presence of a gravitational field ala the equivalence principle? If so, should we not use the second formula? I am sure that I hold a severe foundational misunderstanding here. I think I am equating "acceleration $\Longleftrightarrow$ presence of gravity" which is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't acceleration effects mimicked by the presence of a gravitational field ala the principle of equivalence? If so, should we not use the second formula?

You can always use the second formula. The first formula is a special case of the second. Specifically, inertial coordinates in flat spacetime.  The acceleration of the object is irrelevant.

Regarding the equivalence principle, for an accelerating worldline in flat spacetime you may choose to use an inertial coordinate system or a non-inertial coordinate system. If you use the inertial coordinate system then there is no "gravity field" (non-zero Christoffel symbols), and if you use a non-inertial coordinate system then there is. It is the acceleration of the coordinates that defines the presence or absence of the "gravity field" (non-zero Christoffel symbols). The acceleration of any given worldline is not directly relevant. It is only indirectly relevant to the extent that you choose to base your coordinate system around that worldline.

Comment: But depending on which formula we use, we'll get a different result.

Comment: If spacetime is curved and you use a flat metric, you’ll get the wrong answer. What made you think you are supposed to use the first formula?

Comment: @G.Smith What I understand is that if spacetime is flat but the object is accelerating, then I can use the first formula. Is this part correct? Now, let me state the confusing bit. If an object is accelerating, isn't that acceleration effect replaced by/mimicked by a gravitational field?

Comment: *If spacetime is flat but the object is accelerating, then I can use the first formula* Yes. *If an object is accelerating, isn't that acceleration effect replaced by/mimicked by a gravitational field?* No. When I accelerate in my car, I don’t curve spacetime.

Comment: @G.Smith _"When I accelerate in my car, I don’t curve spacetime."_ This bugs me. If you are not allowed to look outside, how will you know whether you're really accelerating or there is a horizontal gravitational field that pushes me against my seat? I mean, I can vaguely guess that you must be right but I cannot fully convince myself.

Comment: @mithusengupta “But depending on which formula we use, we'll get a different result.” As I said in the answer in the specific case of inertial coordinates in flat spacetime they are identical. In that case (and that case only) $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$. If you use the first formula any other time it is wrong. If you use the first formula for inertial coordinates in flat spacetime it is identical to the second.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 *If you are not allowed to look outside, how will you know...* Simply. In GR, there is no gravitational field that could push you against the seat (assuming tidal forces are neglectable), so the car needs to be accelerating - there is no other explanation.